# Send EXTRA data via PendingIntent problem

Tags: android

Hi I'm tried to send extra data via PendingIntent.

This is my code

```
//**1**
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class); 
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
    appWidgetId); 
            intent.putExtra(BaseConfigurationActivity.EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE, 
    2); 
            // put appWidgetId here or intent will replace an intent of 
    another widget 
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getService(context, appWidgetId, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.gridview_button, 
    pendingIntent); 

//**2**
            intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class); 
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
    appWidgetId); 
            intent.putExtra(BaseConfigurationActivity.EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE, 
    1); 
            // put appWidgetId here or intent will replace an intent of 
    another widget 
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, appWidgetId, 
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listview_button, 
    pendingIntent);
```

In my code it assign pendingIntent to two button gridview_button with EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE 2
and listview_button with EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE 1

when I click on gridview_button and it call UpdateService class
I also got EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE value is  "1"

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to give us some more details. What is exactly your problem ? Do you have any errors ? If so, can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: sorry for unclear question. In code "gridview_button" have PendingIntent with EXTRA data "EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE" = "2" when I run my code I also got EXTRA_WIDGET_MODE value "1"

Comment: Write your own answer please and then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I found problem this happen because I send the same "requestCode"

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, appWidgetId
```

It should be like this

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0 
PendingIntent.getService(context, 1
```

Comment: also if you are just changing the bundle data, setting the action to something like 'foo1' and 'foo2' works... ie intent.setAction("action1");//since technically request code isn't fully supported yet.

Answer (score 8):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Change flag to `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer I guess would be use the flag

```
FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

This will reuse existing pending intents but replace their extra data.

Comment: I guess this was the problem, not the solution (I ran into the same prob). If you need multiple pendingIntents which differ only on ExtraData, then FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT does as it says: it overwrites the existing pendingIntents.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the Intent that was used to create the Pending intent has any extras already in it then the new intent's extras are ignored. For example, if you follow the sample in the Android docs for building a Widget like so

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
toastIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);
```

Then the line

```
toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
```

Will prevent your new intent's extras from sticking. I removed that line and my stuff worked